# Manually configure monitor resolution in Fedora Core 13?

Tags: display, resolution, fedora, fedora-13

Is there any way to manually configure the monitor resolution in Fedora Core 13? Right, now my [HP f2105](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c00665777&tmp_task=prodinfoCategory&lc=en&dlc=&cc=us&lang=&product=461639) won't go past 800x600.

Answer (score 1):

Xorg in Fedora 13 tries its best to find a good resolution given the video card driver and what it detects. If you believe that it's detecting things incorrectly then the first thing you should do is examine the Xorg log, located at `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`.

Comment: I will check it out.